# Assigning a parameter value as class for an element doesn't work on even number of clicks

Tags: jquery, html, dom

On checking the `CheckAll` check box I am checking all the checkboxes on a page and moving the parent, which is  a table, of each of those checked boxes into another div. And  On Unchecking the `CheckAll` check box I have to uncheck all the checked checkboxes on the page and remove the copied table elements from the div.

```
/*******************Check and Uncheck all the checkboxes on the page***********************************/
$("#dvReports #checkAll").click(function () 
{
    var pageNum = $("#dtlRptPrvNxtLnk .selected.link_look").html();
    alert(pageNum);
    if ($("#dvReports #checkAll").is(':checked')) 
    {
        $("#dvReports input[type=checkbox]").each(function () 
        {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            // If a listing is selected then move it to  divPrintContainer, 
            // which is buried inside _reportLayout.cshtml
            $(this).closest('table')
                .toggleClass(pageNum)
                .clone()
                .appendTo("#divPrintContainer");
        });
    } 
    else 
    {
        $("#dvReports input[type=checkbox]").each(function () 
        {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        });

        $("#divPrintContainer").children('table.'+ pageNum ).remove();
    }
});
```

I am running into the following issue :

1. For every even number of clicks on the `CheckAll` checkbox the `.toggleClass(pageNum)`  is not working.
   i.e.  The first time I check the **Checkall**  `.toggleClass(pageNum)` assigns the class name. Now I uncheck the `Checkall`. And again I check the **Checkall** it won't assign the pagenum as class (but I do see the alert with the pageNum).

[HTML in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XMLGw/10/)

Comment: any chance we can see some of the HTML this is running against?

Comment: Using $("#dvReports #checkAll") makes me think you are not using unique IDs, which is not allowed.

Comment: @devrooms I updated the question with HTML in the jsfiddle.

Comment: do you want to move the complete table every time or only the rows that are selected?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever `untoggle` your class.  Which is why it is present every other time.

Comment: @kyle how can i untoggle?

Comment: @BumbleBee Is this what you were looking for?  There were 2 issues. 1) You never removed the class you had added to the tables. 2) Your HTML id didn't match the id you used in your JS.  http://jsfiddle.net/XMLGw/17/  Toggle class first adds the class and then removes the class.  So your checkboxes were only being toggled when the `Select All` checkbox was clicked every other time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it appears the problem is with this line:

```
$(this).closest('table').toggleClass(pageNum).clone().appendTo("#divPrintContainer");
```

My interpretation of this line is as follows:

1. Search upwards through the DOM tree to get the reference to the
   table that contains the checkbox
2. Toggle the class called pageNum i.e. add it first time, remove it second time, etc
3. Copy the table to a new DOM element
4. Append the new element to the container

So, when you click Check All, it toggles the class on the table nearest each text box, but never toggles this off.  When you select it the second time, it removes the class then copies it to the container.

Simply, change the line to the following:

```
$(this).closest('table').clone().addClass(pageNum).appendTo("#divPrintContainer");
```

Comment: Thank u. with ur upadte the copying of the table to #divPrintContainer is not happening.

Comment: In your fiddle your div is called divTestPrintContainer - see amended fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w7F3r/

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `toggleClass` within the `if ($("#dvReports #checkAll").is(':checked')) {`

As a result, `toggleClass` is only called when checking but not unchecking.  Therefor, click 1, `toggleClass` adds the class.  Click 2, checkbox is unchecked, no change to the class.  Click 3, checkbox is checked, `toggleClass` is called only for the 2nd time, removing the class.

I believe what you want is to call it every time it is clicked, not only when it is checked.  Remove it from the `if`.

Comment: On click 1, i need to add the class and move the table to a div. On click 2,checkbox is unchecked, i need to remvoe the copied table from the div.

Comment: Perhaps you intended to call `toggleClass` (or `addClass`) on the clone instead of on the original element?  You currently call `toggleClass` on the original element, before cloning.